# how to hide a row without deleting item from dataprovidor in DataGrid...AS3,Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

How we can **hide a row** at specific index of DataGrid in AS3 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If dataProvider of your `DataGrid` is `ArrayCollection` you can specify `filterFunction` property for it, something like that

```
dataProvider.filterFunction =
    function (item:Object):Boolean{
        if (dataProvider.getItemIndex(item)==indexOfRowYouWantToHide){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
```

The item will still be in ArrayCollection but will be made invisible by the filter. Not the most efficient solution but it works. You need to call

```
dataProvider.refresh();
```

to apply the filter.

**UPDATE:** To access raw, unfiltered data of `ArrayCollection` you should use `list` property, so if you hid item at index 0 and still want to be able to access it you do that like this:

```
dataProvider.list.getItemAt(0);
```

Comment: +1.  The filtering API is built into the ListCollectionView class.  Any class extending that will offer the same filtering functionality.  XMLListcollection is another option in the Flex Framework.  I know there are other implementations out there in the community, such as the DataCollection from Farata Systems folk.

Comment: i used this to hide row at 0 index but when i get the item from dataprovidor at index 0.. item is removed from dataprovidor .. i want value should be in dataprovidor but just dont appear.

Comment: is it possible to use dataDescriptor... ?

Answer (score 0):

No (easy) way. You can try to subclass DataGrid to add this functionality, but this will be really heavy task.

Comment: Looks like @2DH has an easy way!